# Идентификация nullable типа

Tags: c#

Есть функция, принимающая `object arg`. В самой функции требуется получить тип переданного объекта. В общем случае все просто:

```
var argType = arg.GetType()
```

Но если передать в функцию пустой nullable объект, то код выше приведет к исключению.

Можно добавить в сигнатуру функции необязательный параметр `Type type = null`, и для nullable типов передавать туда `typeof(T?)`. Но мне этот способ не очень нравится, можно ли обойтись без этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант еще можно добавить дженерик. Вызов не изменится:

```
public string ToFormat<T>(T arg){
    var argType = typeof(T);
    // ... //
}
```

Comment: Только так. Если nullable тип имеет значение null, то он не упаковывается (boxing).